# Alter the color of table-row on hover when color set

Tags: html, css, hover, background-color

I have an http table created dynamically by the server from data from a database. Depending on some values, the server sets the table row `style="background-color:#RRGGBB"`. This value is from a string in the database, so CSS is not an option.
This all works nice and well, but this overrides the CSS which sets the background-color for hovering on a table row.

In this case, how do I change the color of the table row on hover, perferably while maintaining some resemblance to the color from the database?

```css
table tr:nth-child(2n):hover {
  background-color: silver;
}

table tr:nth-child(2n+1):hover {
  background-color: gray;
}

table tr:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: #DDDDEE;
}

table tr:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background-color: #CCCCDD;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Line1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Line2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Line3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:#FFDDDD;">
    <td>Line4 - With color, no hover effect</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:#DDFFDD;">
    <td>Line5 - With color, no hover effect</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Line6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Line7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Line8</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: now what u want just u want to have hover effect on line4 and line5 ?

Comment: you could use !important to override the background-color on hover. (like this: background-color: #ddddee !important;

Comment: @AmareshSM yes, exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply a partially-transparent box-shadow to each element on hover.

```css
table tr:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 99999px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);;
}

table tr:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: #DDDDEE;
}

table tr:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background-color: #CCCCDD;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Line1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Line2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Line3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:#FFDDDD;">
    <td>Line4 - With color, no hover effect</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:#DDFFDD;">
    <td>Line5 - With color, no hover effect</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Line6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Line7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Line8</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I found 0.05 alpha to be more applicable to my case. but thank you very much. I didn't even know something like `box-shadow` existed

Comment: Brilliant idea to create the alpha mask that applies only to background color (:

Answer (score 0):

you can use onMouseOver and onMouseOut events to hover.

```
onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='grey'" 
onMouseOut="this.style.backgroundColor='#FFDDDD'"
```

```css
table tr:nth-child(2n):hover {
  background-color: silver;
}

table tr:nth-child(2n+1):hover {
  background-color: gray;
}

table tr:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: #DDDDEE;
}

table tr:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background-color: #CCCCDD;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Line1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Line2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Line3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:#FFDDDD;" onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='grey'" onMouseOut="this.style.backgroundColor='#FFDDDD'">
    <td>Line4 - With color, no hover effect</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-Color:#DDFFDD;" onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='silver'" onMouseOut="this.style.backgroundColor='#DDFFDD'">
    <td>Line5 - With color, no hover effect</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Line6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Line7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Line8</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'd rather not use `!important` if I can help it.

Comment: This doesn't meet the spec of the hover color being similar to the original one.

Comment: I'll just stick with the box shadow thing. thank you anyway.

Comment: u can also use  onMouseOver and onMouseOut @FalcoGer

Answer (score 0):

Just add td in your hover

```css
table tr:nth-child(2n) td:hover {
  background-color: silver;
}

table tr:nth-child(2n+1) td:hover {
  background-color: gray;
}

table tr:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: #DDDDEE;
}

table tr:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background-color: #CCCCDD;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Line1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Line2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Line3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:#FFDDDD;">
    <td>Line4 - With color, no hover effect</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:#DDFFDD;">
    <td>Line5 - With color, no hover effect</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Line6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Line7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Line8</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```